# Что такое -ез- в слове «любезность»?

Tags: этимология, историческое-словообразование

Что это за странный словообразовательный элемент "ез", почему он присутствует только в слове *любезность*?

Comment: Элемент "езн/есн" встречается еще и в: болеть – болезный, помпа – помпезный, холод (или колода) – колодезный, небо – небесный, ровня – ровесник, чудо – чудесный, древо – древесный, тело – телесный, слово – словесный

Comment: но небо, чудо, древо,тело, слово - это всё же вроде немного из другой оперы

Comment: @guaranteen вы намешали какую-то кашу из слов, у которых разная история. Например, _ес_ в небесном -- это вообще, так сказать, расширение основы, носившее систематический характер; помпезный -- это вообще французское pompeuse...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Элемент *-ез-*, видимо, суффиксоид (суффикс?). Он участвовал в образовании некоторых других прилагательных (ср. *бол**ез**ненный*), а также встречается в диалектах (например, *глупезный* 'глупый'). Из-за того что ему трудно (нельзя?) приписать значение, нельзя сказать наверняка, морфема это или нет.

Почему редко встречается в словах? Потому что так сложилось.

Answer (score 2):

В словаре Ефремовой указан **суффикс ОЗН/ЕЗН**, причем он считается продуктивным и регулярным.

Суффикс обозначает **изобилие признака,** названного мотивирующим словом: ***помпезный, религиозный, грациозный, амбициозный***. В медицинской терминологии: ***тифозный, гриппозный*** (имеющий отношение к болезни).

**Из словаря Черных:** В древнерусском книжном языке с XI века: ***любьзный*** — приятный, ***любьзнивый*** — полный любви.

О.-с. основа: ljub-ьz-n-. Суффикс ьz встречается редко. Однако, др.-рус. ***любьжа*** — от ljubьzja, любовное средство, приворотный корень.

Сравнить также ст.-сл. ***лобъзати*** — целовать, о.-с. основа lobъz-.

Comment: Интересно, а суффикс "езь" в слове "кладезь" (неисчерпаемый источник), это тот же "езн" или что то самомстоятельное?

Comment: Еще в 16 веке употреблялась форма кладязь (старославянский вариант). Предполагается, что эта форма заимствована в праславянскую эпоху из германских языков (как версия). Колодец - это переоформленный вариант от колодезь (сравнить: студенец).